# How to get the key in the dictionary startswith

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below dictionary

```
my = {
  "1": {
    "flag": 1,
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1",
    "id": 33,
    "Out1": "Cost"
  },
  "2": {
    "flag": 1,
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1",
    "id": 34,
    "Out1": "Rev"
  },
  "3": {
    "flag": 0,
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1",
    "Out1": "Rev"
  },
  "4": {
    "flag": 0,
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1",
    "Out1": "Cost"
  }
}
```

I would like to

- extract the key startswith Col, and output column
- check whether flag is 1

I have written the following piece of code but that doesn't seem to give the expected result.

```
{ k: {v: {i:x for i, x in v.items() if i.startswith('Col'),v['output'] if flag=1}.values()} for k,v in my.items()}
```

Expected result

```
{
  "1": {
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1"
  },
  "2": {
    "Col1": "Val1",
    "Col2": "Val2",
    "output": "Out1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
{k : {kk : vv for kk, vv in v.items() if kk.startswith('Col') or kk == 'output'} for k,v in my.items() if v['flag']}
```

---

```
{'1': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'},
 '2': {'Col1': 'Val1', 'Col2': 'Val2', 'output': 'Out1'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
my = {
    "1": {
        "flag": 1,
        "Col1": "Val1",
        "Col2": "Val2",
        "output": "Out1",
        "id": 33,
        "Out1": "Cost"
    },
    "2": {
        "flag": 1,
        "Col1": "Val1",
        "Col2": "Val2",
        "output": "Out1",
        "id": 34,
        "Out1": "Rev"
    },
    "3": {
        "flag": 0,
        "Col1": "Val1",
        "Col2": "Val2",
        "output": "Out1",
        "Out1": "Rev"
    },
    "4": {
        "flag": 0,
        "Col1": "Val1",
        "Col2": "Val2",
        "output": "Out1",
        "Out1": "Cost"
    }
}

result = {k: {v: my[k][v] for v in my[k] if (v.startswith('Col') or v.startswith('output'))} for k in
      my if my[k]['flag']}

print(json.dumps(result, indent=1))
```

Or, if you prefer using regular expressions, consider using `re.match(start_string, input_string)`. This will match for strings at the beginning.

```
import re

result = {k: {v: my[k][v] for v in my[k] if re.match('Col', v) or re.match('output', v)} for k in my if
      my[k]['flag']}
```

**Result**

> ```
> {
>  "1": {
>   "Col1": "Val1",
>   "Col2": "Val2",
>   "output": "Out1"
>  },
>  "2": {
>   "Col1": "Val1",
>   "Col2": "Val2",
>   "output": "Out1"
>  }
> }
> ```